# Run the tests with the correct database (teamcity and cakephp)

Tags: cakephp, phpunit, teamcity

I want to test some methods of my project, I'm using cakephp with phpunit. 
I'm trying to run the tests automatically in the Teamcity, but when the teamcity run the tests, it do it using the default database not the test database , I want to the teamcity use the test database just like when I run the test in the phpstorm with phpunit.

This is the error that give me the Teamcity:

> MissingDatasourceConfigException: The datasource configuration "default" was not found in database.php

sorry for my english!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any Fixtures which imports records or the schema from the default database? In that case you have to create the default database and which is probably why you're seeing this error message.

Comment: @Martin_Persson I have two database, the default database and the test database, and I use the test database with fixtures when I run the test in phpstorm with phpunit, but when I run he task in Teamcity, it use the default database

Comment: What I mean is, you may be doing schema lookups on the default database which would require it to exist as well as the test database. I assume you would get the same errors in PHPStorm as in TeamCity if you remove your default database config?